# OS X launchd script fails to run at startup?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, launchd

I made a launchd script to run general scripts for me at startup but I can't get it to work. I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. This is my /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.craig.startup.items file (I just noticed it doesn't have a ".plist" extension. I'll add the extension and reboot after posting this question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.craig.startup.items</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/cliff/startup/onlaunchd</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And /Users/cliff/startup/onlaunchd contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

log=/Users/cliff/startup/status.log
echo "`date` running startup scripts." >> $log
pushd /Users/cliff/startup/scripts/
for each in `ls`; do echo "`date` Running $each" >> $log; sh $each; done
popd
```

There are further scripts involved but the onlaunchd doesn't ever fire because I never see the log output in /Users/cliff/startup/status.log. If I run it directly as root it works just fine. What am I missing other than potentially the extension?

Comment: Have you run `sudo launchctl load -w  /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.craig.startup.items.plist`?

Comment: ahh...  I get "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.craig.startup.items.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions". I just set the ownership to root:wheel and that seems to fix it on the cmd line. Why don't you move this comment to an answer so I can accept if all goes well on reboot? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run daemon before restart:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.craig.startup.items.plist
```

Also pelase set +x permission `chmod +x /Users/cliff/startup/onlaunchd` and update plist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Users/cliff/startup/onlaunchd</string>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, however I can't accept this as an answer until 3 minutes elapses! Thanks again!

Comment: Oh no, now it doesn't seem to be running my scripts with root privileges when I reboot. It only runs w/ root when I use the cmd line you gave me. I thought launchd scripts always ran as root? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you encrypted your home folder? Well, you can run a script for single user. If this is ok, you can place plist to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` then set right permissions `chown <YOUR_USER>:staff com.craig.startup.items.plist` and launch daemon `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.craig.startup.items.plist`. For test please logout-login.

Comment: I think my home folder is encrypted. (not quite sure) It's a newly acquired company owned Mac and I'm still not sure what kind of encryption anti-virus stuff is running. (They added McAfee and a bunch of other stuff.) I'm confused. If I run it as a LaunchAgent then it will run at my user privilege level which won't work. I need it to run as root.

Comment: You can check FileVault status running `sudo fdesetup status`. I think if home folder is encrypted launchctl can't run file from `/Users/cliff/startup` directory, try to move sh-file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or other place (`/usr/local/etc`).

Comment: Oh, never mind. It actually is running as root. The script under /Users/cliff/startup/scripts/ (that I've committed from the question) is just not giving me the desired behavior because it runs prior to the process it is attempting to control. It's an order of operations issue. I'll have to hack in a delay or find a better way. Thanks again! I've already accepted you answer!

Comment: I'm trying to run a kextunload command on startup to disable something. That's more core objective.